# Is there a QuickSight API to process exported analyses?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Amazon QuickSight has recently added functionality to export and import analyses:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-quicksight-api-capabilities-to-accelerate-your-bi-transformation/

However, the exported files have a lot of hard coded ARNs, UUIDs, etc. They need some extra processing before QuickSight can actually import an exported analysis in another account.

Is there a QuickSight API I missed (or some other tool) that already does this?

Or will I have to build this myself?

Comment: Have you tried to create a cloudformation template out of it with parameters which you can change in other account?

Comment: It's not CloudFormation, though, it's a QuickSight specific JSON format. It's meant to be used by `create-analysis` but when I try to run the import I get a ton of errors 

Comment: Yes, I got it. But you can define any resources with CF, you wanted also yo parameterize it for imports in other environment/accounts? Take a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-quicksight-analysis.html

Comment: That's the old API and it doesn't do what I want, unfortunately. It needs an existing template in a QuickSight account. I want to create an analysis from scratch after exporting an existing one. I want to create cross account pipelines for multiple environments. Think configuration as code. So it has to start from something in a Git repo, not in QuickSight.